# Why can't I set a cookie and redirect?

Tags: http, cookies, redirect

I'm having a problem setting a cookie and doing a `302` redirect
In chrome the cookie is not being set (I haven't tested safari), in other browsers I was having the same problem until I added `Path=/` to the cookie an now it works.

This is how the header looks; the status is `302 Found`

```
Content-Type    text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Expires Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Set-Cookie  alasca-flash=error-Message<Required<error-Name<Required<error-Sex<Required<error-Age<Required<;Path=/
Location    /messages/sdf
Content-Length  0
Server  Jetty(6.1.x)
```

Any idea on why the cookie is not set? Or any workaround?

Comment: This worked for me `'Set-Cookie': 'authenticatedUser=tcjebfkbskuv;Path=/'`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

See this question: [Safari doesn't set Cookie but IE / FF does](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1144894/825757)

It mentions [this bug report in WebKit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3512) (due to AFC)