# How to set cookies with redirect in Pylons

Tags: python, cookies, redirect, pylons

In light of the cookie-handling bugs affecting Safari and Chrome ([see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621499/why-cant-i-set-a-cookie-and-redirect)), and Pylons implementation of redirect_to as an exception, is it possible to reliably set a tracking cookie and redirect at the same time? Is the META refresh method looked down upon?

Answer (score 1):

Drilling down a bit, the [webkit folks say it's not their problem](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3512), so the possible solutions aren't as pretty.  One possible ugly solution: setting the tracking information in the beaker session (if you're using beaker?) and retrieving it from the page that you're redirecting to, setting a cookie at that later stage.