# Flash notice with redirect_to is broken in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I updated to Rails 2.3.10, Rack 1.2.1 and now none of my flash messages are showing up.  I found that during a redirect the notice is passed in like this

```
redirect_to(@user, :notice => "Sorry there was an error")
```

And in my view the flash hash is empty

```
<%= debug flash %>  
!map:ActionController::Flash::FlashHash {}
```

**But you can see the message in the controller.**  What gives?

```
        <%= debug controller.session %>
        session{:home_zip=>"94108", :session_id=>"xxx", :flash=>{:notice=>"Sorry there was an error"}, :user_credentials=>"1baf9c9c0423ce0151ec32e24cc422f07309e4ba503eb4830635ecc115da217809997324374bb273b3fb792895c9741a8b8c9ea4267771a1bd149de5b9179ea0", :user_credentials_id=>22, :home_market_id=>11}
        Edit Profile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just ran into this too. All our flash messages disappear with redirect, but not when set in the controller explicitly.

Does not work:

```
  def create
    if @obj.save
      flash[:notice] = "The #{cname.humanize.downcase} has been created."
      redirect_back_or_default redirect_url
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

This does work:

```
 def show
    @user = current_user
    flash[:notice] = "Hello -- this will show up fine"
  end
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you check the rails bug tracker? I still use the old fashioned setter `flash[:notice] = message` and it works fine, so it seems to be a redirect_to method problem.

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/

Did you try `redirect_to url, :flash => { :notice => "notice" }`, as a work around?

Comment: Thanks but I tried that too but it looks like the flash method that is called from the view is broken.

Answer (score 4):

The code below should work:

`redirect_to(@user, {:notice => "Sorry there was an error"})`

I'm guessing this is due to changes in Ruby and not in Rails, because it looks like a token parsing priority change in the compiler.

Comment: It worked for me, in my case it was a `model_path model` before the flash that was causing the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

This could be an issue with cookies. Long story short, cookies don't get if you redirect immediately afterwards. Assuming that Rails implements `flash` using cookies, the redirect is your problem.

Sources:

http://persistall.com/archive/2008/01/25/cookies--redirects--nightmares.aspx
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621499/why-cant-i-set-a-cookie-and-redirect