# User not signed out until refresh

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am facing a problem with my user signout method. Most of the time the method will sign out the current only after a refresh. To make that more clear it goes something like this. User signs out, page is redirected to the home page and still shows the user as signed in with all of the options available to a signed in user displaying in the header. The user is not signed out fully until either refreshing the page. Sometimes it works as inteded but most of the time it doesn't.

Here is my SessionController destroy method:

```
  def destroy
    close_project
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_url
  end
```

And my SessionHelper:

```
  def sign_in(user)
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    remember_token = User.encrypt(cookies[:remember_token])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
  end

  def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end
```

Any idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably facing a caching problem. If the home_url can be visited by both logged in and logged out users it is important to mark the page at least private cacheable. Does it also happen with development environment?

Your problem may also be related to this one:
[Why can't I set a cookie and redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621499/why-cant-i-set-a-cookie-and-redirect)