# Adding cookie and then sending redirect to different domain causes cookie loss

Tags: jsf, servlets, redirect, cookies

I am adding cookies using `response.addCookie` and then redirect using `response.sendRedirect` to an URL in different domain. Cookie path is already set to "/".

```
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) Facescontext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalcontext().getResponse();
response.addCookie(cookie);
response.sendRedirect("http://different.domain.com/xyz.xhtml");
```

I had observed in debug mode and inspecting the response objects at each level cookies are lost before calling the "xhtml" page itself.

I'm using Tomcat 7.0.26. JDK 1.7 and JSF 2.0.

Comment: There is a similar question and the answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621499/why-cant-i-set-a-cookie-and-redirect

Answer (score 0):

This is a security violation. You can't set response cookies for a different domain than the one on which the request was sent to. You can at most share cookies between different subdomains like `foo.example.com` and `bar.example.com` by setting the cookie domain to `.example.com`, with the leading period.

Look for another solution for the functional requirement you had in mind. A commonly used one is sending an long unique autogenerated value as a "token" as a request parameter in the redirect URL.

Comment: Thanks BalusC, currently it's the way coded. Strange behavior is these cookies are present if I deploy the same application on WAS server and loosing them on TomCat Servers :(