# Safari's annoying cookie problem. How do I work around it effectively?

Tags: php, cookies, safari

In case you dont know what safari's cookie problem, here's are a link to it: [Safari doesn't set Cookie but IE / FF does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144894/safari-doesnt-set-cookie-but-ie-ff-does).

I got some problem with it. Compared to the answer in the link I have a user-login cookies set with user-id and hash. In the login page(login.php) I have :

```
<form action="serverScripts/login/checkLogin.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="loginUserName" id="loginUserName" class="loginForms" value="E-mail" />
        <input type="password" name="loginPassword" id="loginPassword" class="loginForms" value="Password" />
        <input type='submit' id="signInButton" class='button' value='Sign in'/>
</form>
```

If it verifies correctly with the database the `checkLogin.php` scripts set the cookies and redirects the user to index.php. But the problem is that Safari don't set cookies on http 302 statuses, which enoyes me pretty much. all other web browser does it. But the answer in the link I provided said that I shall set the cookies on the entry? If I understand correctly that means on my login.php page. How can I do that? via AJAX(I must verify the user with username and password!) very ineffective I think. Is there an another solution to this problem? Hate Safari the link is one year old hasn't corrected the Safari bug yet.

Comment: would you mind instead opening a bug report with safari developers regarding not being able to set cookies regardless of http status code issued by the server?  As far as I know, cookie handling should be completely independent of the status the server arbitrarily responds with.  Cookies and response codes have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: I think the problem lies in that they are not sending the set cookies back to my server. I asked a new question for this take a look