# rails not picking session data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am implementing a payment gateway in my app. 
Its like this:
The user fills the form with necessary details, along with a field containing `return_url(say http://myapp.com/ebs_payment/ebs_response?dr={somedata})` and submit the form to a secure payment site. After the transaction is complete, the secure site puts some encrypted data into my param {dr} and the user is redirected back to the return url. The problem here is, when the user returns to the app with the `return_url`, the application fails to pick up the session data and returns a `nil` value.

Before submitting the form, I put the object `@fdPaymentDets` in to session.

Here is my controller:

```
class EbsPaymentController < ApplicationController
  #before_filter :login_required,:check_user_authenticate  
  #access_control [:ebs_response] => ('user')

  def ebs_response
    @fdPaymentDets = session["fd_payment_details"]

    @deal = Deal.find(@fdPaymentDets.deal_id)

    @categories = find_all_categories    
  end

  private
  def find_all_categories
     @sp = SitePreference.find(:first)
     Category.find(:all,:limit => @sp.categories_display_limit,:order => 'position')
  end

end
```

When the user is redirected to the return url `(http://myapp.com/ebs_payment/ebs_response?dr={encrypted_data})` from the secure site, rails is not picking the `@fdPaymentDets` object from session and making it `nil` thus resulting in an error when accessing data from the `nil` object.

The surprising thing is that, when I put the same `return_url` in my browser by hand, the session data is neatly picked and everything goes well.

Am missing any thing here? What could be the obvious reason? 
Any help appreciated.

Comment: I have observed the same problem, I wish my question or your gets an answer, this is pretty serious stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies and redirects are messy and bug prone (from a browser's implementation perspective). 
Take a look at

[Safari doesn't set Cookie but IE / FF does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144894/safari-doesnt-set-cookie-but-ie-ff-does)

Suggestion would be to change the implementation to set the session first in the show action, and then update the value before the redirect