# Google Chrome (and IE) refusing to set my cookie with method setcookie in PHP

Tags: php, google-chrome, cookies, web

I was looking for an answer on stackoverflow but none them could fix my problem.
I have a website hosted on http://machine/~lcavaill/folder/

In php I use

```
setcookie( COOKIE_AUTH, $cookie, $expiration, COOKIE_PATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false, true )
```

with the following variables

```
define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'machine' );
define( 'COOKIE_PATH', '/~lcavaill/folder/' );
define( 'COOKIE_AUTH', 'foobar' );
$expiration = time() + 300;
```

when looking at the response header I defintely find the Set-Cookie header

```
Set-Cookie:test=lcavaille%7C1335420792%7C44baaa2b2eb43cfb8ab2d66f74afd11e; expires=Thu, 26-Apr-2012 06:13:12 GMT; path=/~lcavaill/folder/; domain=machine; httponly
```

But for the next request on another page the cookie is not set, I couldn't find it anywhere in Chrome (or IE) but it works as expected in Firefox.

So far I checked :

1. If client and server time were in sync
2. If Chrome privacy settings are OK (Allow local data to be set is enabled and no exceptions)
3. $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] match COOKIE_DOMAIN variable
4. Enable/Disable http_only
5. Set cookie path to /
6. Set expiration to 0

Do you have any ideas for me ?!

Cheers,
Leo

Comment: Does it work when you don't explicitly set the cookie path? I.e., check if something as simple as setcookie('test', '1'); works.

Comment: @Olaf not setting the path does not change anything. And a simple request works and sets a cookie test : 
`Set-Cookie: blabla=lcavaille%7C1335425726%7Cab4a9752133970811c50ca69ccfa6206; expires=Thu, 26-Apr-2012 07:35:26 GMT; domain=machine; httponly

Set-Cookie: test=1`

Comment: I'd suggest you install the "Edit this cookie" extension in Chrome (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg), then change the cookie definition in your code step-by-step and check what happens and when the cookie isn't set anymore. It'll give you a lot of useful information.

Answer (score 0):

these are just a wild guesses, but:

- some browsers ignore the set-cookie header on redirect responses:
  [Safari doesn't set Cookie but IE / FF does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144894/safari-doesnt-set-cookie-but-ie-ff-does)
- or on localhost and ip addresses:
  http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=56211

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

More to that, setcookie() worked (returned true) on FF34, Chrome39 and IE8 & IE11 on my development server (win7 64bit, wamp, php 5.3.9), but it would return false on the production site (debian, php 5.4.35) for Chrome and IE.

After some googling and carefully reading the [**setcookie()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) manual I discovered (something I had missed before) that the manual says: `"If output exists prior to calling this function, setcookie() will fail and return FALSE."`

At first I wasn't sure what exactly `If output exists prior to calling this function` means, but apparently there should be no output to the browser in order to set the cookie.

After I moved the problematic line of code before any output, the problem is gone and the code works on the above browsers (both development and production servers), plus on latest FF and Chrome on Android.