# cookie lost in error_page tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

My tomcat (6) is working fine with a 404 error page  properly configured.

I am trying to setup a valve which:
**1) Expires a previously created cookie

2) create a new cookie and put in the response**

It works fine as long as I do not hit the 404 error page. The **new cookie** is lost

I followed the trace... It seems that Tomcat does not forward the response object to the "404 error". Instead a new response object is created.

Does someone hve an idea?

Regards

Comment: Can you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144894/safari-doesnt-set-cookie-but-ie-ff-does to see if you are having the same issue? Going to 404 page is redirecting.

Comment: Thanks Mindas; but it has nothing to see with the browser. The behavior is the same on IE/Firefox/Safari. The newly created cookie did not get through.