# Safari does not completely save the cookie

Tags: asp.net, .net, cookies, safari

I have a program that writes in the cookie on a page, the redirect,

```
SetCookie(key,value);
Response.Redirect("SecondPage.aspx");
```

and tries to read the cookie on the second page.

```
var value = GetCookie(key);
```

As simple as that! It works fine on IE/FF/Chrome, but not in Apple's Safari!

This is how the cookie value looks line in IE/FF/Chrome:

```
flyerName=1111+test+road%2c+LS%2c+MO&flyerPersonId=1241BST34&flyerTemplate=Vertical.pdf&flyerListing=6666&flyerOrg=TESTORG
```

and in Safari:

```
flyerName=1111+test+road
```

apparently Safari has truncated the string after %2C which is comma(,) in ascii table!

P.S. I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144894/safari-doesnt-set-cookie-but-ie-ff-does), but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved! Before saving cookie, do a `Server.UrlEncode(strValue)` and when retrieving that used a `Server.UrlDecode(c.Values.Item(strKey))`

Apparently Safari cannot handle the `","` and `";"` correctly in cookie value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Responce.cookie["PageUrl"].value=your value;
Responce.cookie["PageUrl"].Path="/";
```

now you can access this cookie throught out you application;

Comment: Thx, it didn't work, problem is not with where to store cookie data, it's with storing "," without truncating rest of the cookie.