# Owin cookie authentication set-cookie not saving in browser

Tags: cookies, asp.net-web-api, owin, katana

I am building self-hosted web server on this stack:
OWIN
Nancy
Web Api 2

And I am using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies from Katana for forms-like authentication. I got Set-Cookie header in response, but cookie don't being saved and not being included in next request. So what's the problem? What I am doing wrong?

### Owin startup:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            AuthenticationType = "GM",
            CookieHttpOnly = true,
            CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest,
            CookiePath = "/",
            CookieName = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.CookiePrefix + "GM",
            CookieDomain = "localhost",
        });
```

### Controller code:

```
var context = Request.GetOwinContext();
context.Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties()
    {
        IsPersistent = true
    },
    new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, user.Login)}, "GM"));
context.Response.Headers.Add("Location", new []{ "/" });
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Found);
```

### Response headers:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:0
Date:Wed, 11 Sep 2013 11:11:23 GMT
Expires:-1
Location:/
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Set-Cookie:.AspNet.GM=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE_Cl-sBAAAABui2rBibE0yPXB0-v3C06gAAAAACAAAAAAAQZgAAAAEAACAAAAC1mQV3jGo_WAhMQ-hzsmzgkdbdCclWIAX-msbE0_12zQAAAAAOgAAAAAIAACAAAABuQjBg3EJIka151hvBgtlPGfQ2O_cwNI2VVh86dchTDXAAAAD21O9DnNk4yLU9eddVfY3bT9P1CEudNeLvwohkSTAQBP2onuIQfgl9F99Je5waPddckh2llD2kjftSMQPhzgE9vKm-_wE42hXhc9FIgfxpD5AdaeGatwpEcwDfGJJdpQnObX1pbjEFIXLVJxGm5qMUQAAAAC8AiFTaXmzrfRy4-jR6zqMmSKddzddmiBLGClAckWOy6W2YWdf50N2zhIj_MwN8-zi-B0tlv87pzAt-6RDZYZs; domain=localhost; path=/; expires=Wed, 25-Sep-2013 11:11:24 GMT; HttpOnly
```

Comment: I've got the cookie sending back and fourth but my next requests are not validated, were you able to accomplish that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I resolved the issue. It was because 'domain=localhost'. It seems to 'localhost' isn't valid value for domain parameter.

Comment: Just helped me out-- this solution is still relevant. Thanks! **EDIT:** my issue was that I did not specify a domain at all. It works correctly when debugging locally, but does not work when deployed to a server environment.

Answer (score 0):

You could be encounting a similar issue to: [Safari doesn't set Cookie but IE / FF does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144894/safari-doesnt-set-cookie-but-ie-ff-does)

Try setting the HttpStatusCode to HttpStatusCode.Ok

Some browsers will only accept cookies from a certain response code (like 200, 302).

Comment: Sad, but cookie don't saving in all browsers I've tryed (Chrome, IE, FF). And I've tryed HttpStatusCode.OK, but it doesn't changed anything.

Comment: Did you double check the expires value on the cookie.  It's not expiring immediately, correct?

Comment: As you can see, it expires 25'th September. I've tryed set expiration timespan to 30 days, but no result. Ah, also, I am using non-standart port 8080, can it cause troubles?

Comment: I resolved the issue. It was because 'domain=localhost'. It seems to 'localhost' isn't valid value for domain parameter.