# OWIN ClaimsIdentity not working in IE11

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin

After Signing in using OWIN authentication, the identity's 'IsAuthenticated' is always false in IE11.  It works just fine in Chrome though, any ideas ?

I also reloaded the page to see if secondary request worked, and it does not.  I do see the cookie though in IE's dev tool.

```
//Setup authentication
ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, webUser.User_ID.ToString())
}, "ApplicationCookie");    
request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(identity);

//Check authentication
ClaimsIdentity identity = request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;         

if (!identity.IsAuthenticated) return null; // In IE11, 'IsAuthenticated' is always false and the identity is not a valid  claimsIdentity
```

Here is my Startup code if it helps:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
         {
            AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie",            
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Auth/"),
            CookieDomain = "localhost",
            CookieName = "MyCookie"
         });
```

Comment: Can you see the cookie in the request context?

Comment: Request.Cookies.Count is 0 immediately after calling SignIn in IE11.  In Chrome, the count is 1

Comment: I added the Startup code if that helps diagnose

Comment: Are you opening a pop-up?

Comment: Do you mean a windows authentication dialog, or a javascript new window?  No in both cases.

Comment: Do you have an underscore in your domain or machine name?

Comment: No underscore in domain or machine name.

Comment: Figured it out - localhost isn't valid domain. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739984/owin-cookie-authentication-set-cookie-not-saving-in-browser