# On Safari, cookies are not saved when sent with redirect

Tags: express, cookies, safari

I have implemented an OAuth2 client, in which the first step is to send a user to the relevant 3rd party (facebook for this example), I set them a state cookie, and when they return from facebook I validate that state cookie.

In Chrome, everything is great. When I send the user to the redirect URL, I can see (using inspect element) that they have the `state` cookie I set.
However, when I try on (desktop) safari on latest MacOS, I don't see that cookie.

I set the cookie in the response for my redirect request:

```
res.cookie('state', state.toString(), {
  maxAge: 3600000,
  secure: true,
  httpOnly: true,
});
res.redirect(someRedirectUri);
```

How can I get those cookies to be saved on Safari as well? Am I just setting the cookies wrong?

Answer (score 13):

I think you've found known [WebKit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3512) issue.

So safari is ignoring the Set-Cookie header when encountering the 302 HTTP status

Comment: Thanks. Before o mark this solved do you know a way around this?

Comment: No, I don't know. Just found the related issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144894/safari-doesnt-set-cookie-but-ie-ff-does. But as I can see there are no workarounds...only a lot of questions on the apple/webkit forums without answers...

Comment: Safari 13.1 here, confirming it's still an (absurd) issue.

Comment: Safaria 15.0. Same issue still valid.

Answer (score 2):

Late response but I hope this helps anyone else coming across this issue.

I ran into this issue earlier today. It was happening on iOS Safari and Chrome (Chrome on iOS uses WebKit). The workaround I implemented was changing the initial response to a 200 and return a web page which would do a JavaScript redirect in a few seconds.

Here's the HTML I used:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Redirecting...</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Redirecting...</h1>
    <div>You will be redirected in a moment. If you are not redirected, click the following link: <a id="link" href="https://example.com">Go Now</a></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var host = "https://"+window.location.host;
        document.getElementById("link").setAttribute("href", host);
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.location.href = host;
        }, 3000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This way the Cookies will be set with the response, and the redirect will happen a moment later.

In my case, I was completing an OAuth workflow. You should be able to customize/render the page in a number of ways to meet other requirements.

Comment: [HTML redirects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections#html_redirections) are another option

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question and the answers when investigating a problem I have with cookies and an OAuth2 client (actually oidc).  My problem turned out to be different, so it is not a good answer to the original question, but hopefully it will prevent others reading this from going on a wild goose chase.

I have a backend that sets a session cookie (`__ac_session`) with information that is used during the authentication with the oidc server.  Problems:

1. At first it looked like this cookie was not saved in the browser, because it was sent in a redirect response.  I tried doing the redirect in javascript, from the [answer by Padge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70295152/621201), but that did not help.  Problem was that the cookie was only set on a path (`/acl_users/oidc`) and both Safari and Chrome did not show this cookie when looking at the homepage.  Firefox does show it, but I had unrelated problems with that browser.
2. So the browser *did* get the cookie and sent it along with further requests on that path.  But the cookie never reached the backend.  The problem here was that I had the Varnish caching server in front of the backend, and this removed most cookies, including this one, to improve anonymous caching.

I don't know if you get this with standard Varnish, but with my configuration I did.  Relevant part of the final `varnish.vcl` after I fixed it:

```
/* cookies for pass */
set req.http.UrlNoQs = regsub(req.url, "\?.*$", "");
if (req.http.Cookie && req.http.Cookie ~ "auth_token|__ac(|_(name|password|persistent|session))=") {
    if (req.http.UrlNoQs ~ "\.(js|css|kss)$") {
        unset req.http.cookie;
        return(pipe);
    }
    return(pass);
}
```

My backend is Plone with an oidc plugin. Here is a link to my [full issue report](https://github.com/collective/pas.plugins.oidc/issues/11), created when I did not yet know the cause.