# How is the remember_me cookie set in the HTTP response?

Tags: laravel

For specific reasons I'm logging the user automatically, and set the remember_me cookie so they stay logged in.

- They hit a route like my-app.com/my-login?params=XYZ
- I call Auth::login($user, true);
- I redirect them to a page where they are logged in

It works everywhere, except on iOS Safari (for some reason). There, it logs in, but doesn't remember the user. However if I refresh the final page just after login, it remembers the user!

Any idea why? How/when is the remember_me cookie set in the HTTP response?

Answer (score 0):

10 years from now it was a problem
[Safari doesn't set Cookie but IE / FF does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144894/safari-doesnt-set-cookie-but-ie-ff-does)

Some Safari old versions like (v. 7.0.6) would ignore a cookie. The cookie header looked perfectly fine, almost identical to another cookie which was remembered.

The culprit was the previous cookie header having a malformed expires value. Safari's handling of broken cookie headers is evidently not as robust as that of the other browsers.

So try to use newer safari